# How to Install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4 using Mac OS X?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, mac

Will this work on a Mac? I want to install Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4 but I'm pretty sure `apt-get` isn't compliant with the fruit shell. Is it possible to install using Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (open-source), install a fresh Saucy Salamander on it, and then, install Ubuntu-touch on your nexus 4.